# In MySQL how we can use defined variables in a query

Tags: mysql

```
set @total_balance=0;
select total_balance=if(a.transaction_type='+c') then total_balance=total_balance+a.tran_amount
else if(a.transaction_type='-p'or '-r') then total_balance=total_balance-a.tran_amount
END
from lib_user_account a
where employee_Id='1004';
```

Comment: thought of using sum function?

Answer (score 2):

```
SUM(IF(a.transaction_type='+c', a.tran_amount, -a.tran_amount))
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use sum function in your query as zerkms has mentioned but to answer your question on how to use user defined variables in MYSQL you can use it in the following way in your query

```
select 
  @total_balance:=if(a.transaction_type='+c', @total_balance+a.tran_amount, if(a.transaction_type='-p' or a.transaction_type='-r', @total_balance-a.tran_amount, a.tran_amount))
from 
  lib_user_account a
join 
  (select @total_balance:=0) userVar
where 
  employee_Id='1004';
```

**[REFER FOR MORE INFO ABOUT USER DEFIND VARIABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)**

Comment: but result is row-wise i want a final value.

Comment: Add group by clause for it... GROUP BY employee_id

Comment: @Meherzad: after `GROUP BY` only `a.transaction_type` and `a.tran_amount` values won't be consistent

Comment: We need only the value of sum we are not taking value of `a.transaction_type` and `a.tran_amount`